# How do you programmatically create a webform with a managed_file type?

Tags: 8, webforms, files

I haven't been able to find a single example of how to create a webform with a managed_file type.

The webform initially had the type 'file', but needs to be changed to accept multiple attachments. When the type is changed to 'managed_file', the field for uploading attachments does not render.

Here is my code snippet for the attachment field:

```
7 => array(
    'name' => t('Attachment'),
    'form_key' => 'attachment',
    'type' => 'managed_file',
    'upload_location' => NULL,
    'pid' => 1,
    'weight' => 6,
    'value' => '',
    'required' => '0',
    'extra' => array(
      'directory' => 'story',
      'title_display' => 'before',
      'private' => 0,
      'wrapper_classes' => '',
      'css_classes' => '',
      'filtering' => array(
        'size' => '2 MB',
        'types' => array(
          'gif',
          'jpg',
          'jpeg',
          'png',
          'txt',
          'rtf',
          'html',
          'pdf',
          'doc',
          'docx',
          'ppt',
          'pptx',
          'xls',
          'xlsx',
          'zip',
        ),
        'addextensions' => '',
      ),
      'rename' => '',
      'scheme' => 'public',
      'progress_indicator' => 'throbber',
      'description' => '',
      'attributes' => array(),
      'analysis' => FALSE,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Making a couple of leaps here:

1. I couldn't find a D8 release for Webform so assuming D7
2. I'm assuming by managed_file (which is a FAPI element type) you mean a field API file field, as you mentioned making it accept multiple files (which the managed_file element doesn't have any support for).

So with those in mind...

Webform implements its own set of components, of which file is one type; it doesn't use the field API, so unfortunately you can't attach field API fields of any type to it.

The out-of-the-box file component doesn't support multiple uploads, but there's a contributed module, [Webform Multiple File](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_multiple_file), which does:

> Module Webform Multiple File provides new Webform component for multiple file uploading. The module based on principles of file field widget and has similar design.